# Invalid syntax when trying to define a dictionary in pyQGIS code

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I'm trying to run a code in which I need to use a dictionary, but the terminal acuses 'Invalid Syntax' when I try to define that dictionary. Outside of QGIS the code runs without any problems.

[image]

Comment: " Outside of QGIS the code runs without any problems." are you sure ?

Comment: Please do not paste pictures of code in questions. Instead, place the actual code, as text, so that our volunteers don't need to transcribe your code to show the syntax error in context. Always remember to look above where parse errors are reported, because it's rarely where the error occurred, just where the parser gave up in frustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a closing square bracket and parenthesis on line 12